# different result by 'while' and 'foreach'

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

When looping through array using the 'while' I get good results, but when I do the same with foreach I don't get the same. The SELECT statement returns two rows:
731
732

```
$data = $mysqli->query("SELECT ...");


while($item = $data->fetch_array())
{
echo $item[0]."<br />";
}
```

This returns:
731
732

```
foreach ($data->fetch_array() as $item)
{
echo $item."<br />";
}
```

This returns:
731
731

What am I doing wrong in second aproach with 'foreach'?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Foreach expects an array, while expects an expression

Comment: Your answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553740/difference-between-foreach-and-while

Comment: I think you should do `while($item = $data->fetch())`

Comment: If your versions support it you can use `foreach($data->fetch_all() as $item)`.

Comment: I do not understand how you can ask such questions, really so hard to search in google? you can find your answer in less than 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

That's because the array represents a single row in the returned result set.  In your `foreach` loop, `$data->fetch_array()` will only ever be executed once and that will hold only a single row (which is 731). You'll have to cal `fetch_array()` again to get the next record. You'll have to use a `while` loop to get the records and push them into an array first, and *then* use `foreach`:

```
$resultset = array();
while($item = $data->fetch_array()) {
    $resultset[] = $item;
}

foreach ($resultset as $row) {
    echo $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time whe you call the `fetch_array` method, it returns **one row** from the DB as an array with the values of the fields.
So it does NOT return all the **rows**, but all the **fields** in *one* row.

And when you call it again, it will return *array with the **fields** in the **second row***.

When all the rows in the query are returned, `fetch_array()` returns `FALSE`. In the while loop the `$row` variable becomes `false` and the lopp stops.